# SELECT and than UPDATE updates 2 rows instead of one

Tags: php, mysql

This is driving me crazy for few hours:

I have a list of manufacturers and they have to be updated from time to time. I have to select the oldest updated and then write the current time as the last update time.

This is my script (part of a function inside a class):

```
    public function get_manufacturer () { 

            $sql = '
            SELECT manufacturer_id FROM
            manufacturer
            ORDER BY last_update LIMIT 1
            ';

            $query = $this->query($sql);
            $manufacturer = $query->row;

            //echo $manufacturer['manufacturer_id'];

            $sql = 'UPDATE manufacturer
            SET last_update = '.time().'
            WHERE manufacturer_id ='. $manufacturer['manufacturer_id'];
            $query = $this->query($sql);

            return $manufacturer;

     }
```

The problem is that the update query UPDATES TWO ROWS, instead of one, even if I put `LIMIT 1`. It updates the row with the correct `manufacturer_id` and also the next one.

ANOTHER ODD THING IS THAT EVERYTHING WORKS NORMALLY IF I PUT AN ECHO BETWEEN THE TWO QUERIES.

I've noticed also that everything seems to work normally if I don't use `ORDER BY`. (Unfortunately I need `ORDER BY` in my query).

I was thinking that I have to clear some cache or something like this between the two queries. Please advice!

**UPDATE**

This is the query function, but I've tried just with mysql_query() instead of this function and the result is the same.

```
 public function query($sql) {
    $resource = mysql_query($sql, $this->connection);

    if ($resource) {
        if (is_resource($resource)) {
            $i = 0;

            $data = array();

            while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($resource)) {
                $data[$i] = $result;

                $i++;
            }

            mysql_free_result($resource);

            $query = new stdClass();
            $query->row = isset($data[0]) ? $data[0] : array();
            $query->rows = $data;
            $query->num_rows = $i;

            unset($data);

            return $query;  
        } else {
            return TRUE;
        }
    } else {
        exit('Error: ' . mysql_error($this->connection) . '<br />Error No: ' .    mysql_errno($this->connection) . '<br />' . $sql);
            }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

I have put the same question again but with a simplified (and complete) code that you can test on your own server.
See here: [Why UPDATE used after SELECT chages 2 rows instead of one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7863909/why-update-used-after-select-chages-2-rows-instead-of-one)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Could be something to do with using `$this->query()` to retrieve the data and perform the update. Can you post the code for this function?

Comment: is the function get_manufacturer being called twice in your code?

Comment: I'm sure that the function is not called twice in my code. Please notice that everything works as expected when I use `echo` between the two queries

Answer (score 1):

Either `manufacturer_id` is not `UNIQUE` or you are calling the function twice.

Comment: `manufacturer_id` is set as PRIMARY KEY could not be duplicate. I don't call the function twice and please notice that everything works as expected when I use echo between the two queries.

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting the last_update field in the first query and add it as an AND clause in the update statement to ensure some more uniqueness.

Comment: ***"more uniqueness"***! Nice naming, haven't heard of that before.

Comment: If the issue is to do with manufacturer_id not being unique, this will just make the issue much less likely to occur, not eliminate it. If manufacturer_id's uniqueness is enforced by the database definition, then this step is not needed.

Comment: manufacturer_id is set as PRIMARY KEY could not be duplicate.