# Why UPDATE used after SELECT chages 2 rows instead of one?

Tags: php, mysql

This is very weird and it is driving me crazy, I have a list of manufacturers that have to be updated from time to time. I have to select the oldest updated and then write the current time as the last update time.

The problem is that the update query UPDATES TWO ROWS, instead of one. It updates the row with the correct manufacturer_id and also the next one.

ANOTHER ODD THING IS THAT EVERYTHING WORKS NORMALLY IF I PUT AN `ECHO` BETWEEN THE TWO QUERIES.

I have tested on a Mac XAMPP server, on a Windows XAMPP server and on a Linux server (Hostgator). It works as expected only on the Windows server, on the Mac and Linux the update query affects 2 rows instead of one.

Please test the following script:

make a file test.php and paste the following code:

```
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '') 
    or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
$select = mysql_select_db('test',$connection) 
     or die("Could not select test");

$sql = '
SELECT manufacturer_id FROM
manufacturer
ORDER BY last_update LIMIT 1
';

$query = mysql_query($sql, $connection);
$manufacturer = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

//echo $manufacturer['manufacturer_id'];

$sql = 'UPDATE manufacturer
SET last_update = '.time().'
WHERE manufacturer_id ='. $manufacturer['manufacturer_id'];
mysql_query($sql, $connection);
```

create a database test and run the following SQL query to create the table `manufacturers`:

```
CREATE TABLE `manufacturer` (
  `manufacturer_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `last_update` bigint(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`manufacturer_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

LOCK TABLES `manufacturer` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `manufacturer` DISABLE KEYS */;

INSERT INTO `manufacturer` (`manufacturer_id`, `last_update`)
VALUES
(1,0),
(2,0),
(3,0),
(4,0);

/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `manufacturer` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Call test.php and then check the table to see how many rows have been affected.
If only one row is affected then it works as expected on your server (probably Windows).

If two rows are affected then it has the same strange behavior on your server too. Now uncheck the echo line and you'll see that it works as expected now. Crazy!!!

What is this? It's like somebody is playing tricks on me. Anybody has any idea why this is happening?

Do you think this has something to do with some mysql cache or something like this???

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Have you done `var_dump($manufacturer['manufacturer_id']);` just to prove that it's what you expect?

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce your problem: Win 7, XAMPP.

Comment: Yes and if I put `var_dump` before the second query it works normally, it affects only one row. I think I spent today more than 5 hours checking in every way I could think of and trying to understand.

Comment: It's very strange.  It looks like it should work.  Have you tried putting semicolons after every sql statement to make sure they finish properly?

Comment: I just checked, same odd result with semicolons...

Comment: what about wrapping it with '' -> WHERE manufacturer_id = '$manufacturer_id'?

Comment: test it this way too, doesn't help either...

Comment: Have you looked at your server logs to see how many times the script is actually being hit? The script could be working perfectly but the browser is actually hitting it twice, causing the "double" update. The echo could be causing the browser to hit the page only once as otherwise your script has no output at all.

Comment: @MarcB, you are a genius, the browser was the cause! More exactly firePHP plugin in Chrome. After I disabled it, everything returned to normal.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mark B (see comments) I found out that the browser was the cause. More exactly firePHP plugin in Chrome. After I disabled it, everything returned to normal.

For some reason, firePHP makes the browser to call the page twice when no echo is made.